# android-support-v4 and google play service jar conflict on gson

Tags: android, eclipse, gson, google-play-services, android-support-library

I am using eclipse. In my android project, I originally have the google play service jar library. Then, as soon as I added the android-support-v4 library for Fragment support to build/run, it complains about

Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/Gson...

I think its having a conflict on Gson because it seems that both the android-support-v4 library and the google play service library have Gson.

Any idea, suggestions, or comments of how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

thanks guys...^^

Comment: `android-support-v4.jar` does not appear to have Gson in it. For that matter, I do not see it in the JAR associated with the Play Services SDK. What evidence do you have that these JARs have Gson?

Comment: Hi CommonsWare thanks for you response. I double check that the android-support-v4 and google play library indeed do not have gson in there. I do not know why I am suspecting the android-support-v4 and google play lib. May, I was confused. Nevertheless, I now see the problem now. I have gson in private library and outside of the private library. Thus, unchecking private library solved my problem. thanks again for pointing me to the right direction.^^.

Comment: A bit late, but if you use `gradle`, you can check dependencies using `gradle :NameOfYouProject:dependencies` - it shows all jars and project relationship.